# How to store array of path string in Tempdata MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've action result as in Code that return file by file of image from view

```
[HttpPost]       
    public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/")) || files != null)
        {
            string TempPath = Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/");
            string[] myTempPaths = new string[files.Count()];
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(TempPath, file.FileName);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, ReadData(file.InputStream));
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
                {                        
                    myTempPaths = filePath.Split(',');
                    for (int j = 0; j < files.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        TempData["lev1"] = myTempPaths;
                        for (int k = 0; k < files.Count(); i++)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
```

and i want to store path for each turn in a tempdata 
say i have three Pictures and the action will be entering this method three times and every time with path of the next image
but i lost my way in the middle.

Comment: Question is not clear enough to answer, please correct it.

Comment: What u have returned from Action?

Comment: the action back with images

Comment: You have a for loop with index `i` nested inside another for loop with index `i`. Pretty sure thats not gonna work.

Comment: Not only it's not clear , but it's not even a normal code . what is this ?

Answer (score 1):

this is what I got from your ... whatever it is .
you want to save files and then return their paths ?!

```
[HttpPost]       
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    // reject if no file is send
    if(files == null || !files.Any())
    {
        // return error or throw exception
    }

    // create folder if not exist
    if(!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/")))
    {
        // create folder
    }

    // base path for images
    string TempPath = Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/");
    // list to save file paths
    List<string> myTempPaths = new List<string>();


    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(TempPath, file.FileName);

        // save file
        file.SaveAs(filePath);

        // add path to list
        myTempPaths.Add(filePath);
    }

    // save paths into temp Data
    TempData["lev1"] = myTempPaths;

    return View();
}
```